# How to disable cutting logs by selenium Chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm interesting in catching data from console log of selenium Chromedriver.
Lines could be very long. This is not problem for me - I need full string anyway. But, lines are cut. Could somebody know how to disable cutting of such lines?

From Chrome console log:

```
*07/29/2015 07:56:17,474 [1438145776486z8saqwcu9] [DEB] ["Request complete: https://some_server.addr.com:443/subarg1/subarg2/subarg3/subarg4/subarg5/login?_=5776213 Status: OK (200). **Response payload: ","NEXT_ACTION_12"]***
```

From Chromedriver log:

```
*[29.240][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Console.messageAdded { "message": { "column": 24, "executionContextId": 10, "level": "debug", "line": 18849, "parameters": [ { "type": "string", "value": "07/29/2015 07:56:17,474 [1438145776486z8saqwcu9] [DEB] [\"Request complete: https://some_server.addr.com:443/subarg1/subarg2/subarg3/subarg4/subarg5/login?_=5776213 Status: OK (200). **Response payloa...**" } ], "source": "console-api",*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, looking at the chromedriver sources, it is not possible.
I can't see the way to override this behaviour.
Truncation is made by chromedriver itself. If logged value is string - it's getting truncated to 200 chars, see partial sources below. `FormatValueForDisplay` is calling `TruncateString` for string values

```cpp
Status DevToolsClientImpl::ProcessEvent(const internal::InspectorEvent& event) {
  if (IsVLogOn(1)) {
    VLOG(1) << "DEVTOOLS EVENT " << event.method << " "
            << FormatValueForDisplay(*event.params);
  }
```

```cpp
std::string FormatValueForDisplay(const base::Value& value) {
  scoped_ptr<base::Value> copy(SmartDeepCopy(&value));
  return PrettyPrintValue(*copy);
}
```

```cpp
scoped_ptr<base::Value> SmartDeepCopy(const base::Value* value) {
//skipped code
} else if (value->GetAsString(&data)) {
    TruncateString(&data);
    return scoped_ptr<base::Value>(new base::StringValue(data));
  }
```

```cpp
void TruncateString(std::string* data) {
  const size_t kMaxLength = 200;
  if (data->length() > kMaxLength) {
    data->resize(kMaxLength);
    data->replace(kMaxLength - 3, 3, "...");
  }
}
```

Comment: I used another way to do the requested originally. Used command get_logs("browser") and store them into file directly. In this way them are untruncated

Comment: Does get_logs solve your problem? Is it some custom function?  Or did you mean get_log?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService().LogPath = "1.txt";
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

In that case you should catch full strings.

Comment: In this way I'll got 1 logfile for all instances of ChromeDriver, correct?
It is not acceptable for me. I pass service_log_path directly to each instance. Do we have another way?